# How To Save State of <b>BottomDialogSheetFragment</b> After Dismiss Method

Tags: android

Inside **BottomSheetDialogFragment**, I have a *expandable list view* inside a *navigation view*. Upon clicking on any group item, I would like the selected position background to be changed. It works fine after I implemented a method to handle the click and to change the drawable inside the **adapter**. However, after selecting a list item, it changes the fragment in main activity and it calls the dismiss method afterwards, which results the drawer to lose its state in regards to the position that was selected. Upon opening the drawer again, it sets the background to the 0th index.

The following is my code of the **BottomSheet Dialog**:

```
class BottomNavigationDrawerFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

private lateinit var rootView : View
private lateinit var callback: Callback


internal var expandableListView: ExpandableListView? = null
internal var adapter: ExpandableAdapter? = null
internal var titleList: List<String> ? = null

val data: LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>?>
    get() {
        val listData = LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>?>()

        val list = ArrayList<String>()
        list.add("aaaaaaaa")
        list.add("bbbbb")
        list.add("ccccccccccc")

        listData.put("Home",null)
        listData.put("Search",list)
        listData.put("Contact Us",null)

        return listData
    }



fun fragment(cid : Int) {
    var cat_frag = SubFragment()
    val manager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_lay, cat_frag)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
    return
}


fun register(list:ExpandableAdapter?,position: Int){
    list?.onClickCallBack(position)
}


}
interface Callback{
    fun onClickCallBack(position :  Int)
}
override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, container, false)



    expandableListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView)
    if (expandableListView != null) {
        val listData = data
        titleList = ArrayList(listData.keys)
        adapter = ExpandableAdapter(activity!!, titleList as ArrayList<String>, listData)
        expandableListView!!.setAdapter(adapter)
        expandableListView!!.setOnGroupExpandListener { groupPosition ->
            this.register(adapter,groupPosition)
            when(groupPosition){
                0 -> {

                    val textFragment = fragment1()
                    val manager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
                    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_lay, textFragment)
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                    transaction.commit()
                    this@BottomNavigationDrawerFragment.dismiss()



                }
                2 ->{

                }
            }


            //Toast.makeText(activity!!, (titleList as ArrayList<String>)[groupPosition] + " List Expanded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        expandableListView!!.setOnGroupCollapseListener { groupPosition ->
            when(groupPosition){
                0 -> {
                    val textFragment = fragment1()
                    val manager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
                    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_lay, textFragment)
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null
                    transaction.commit()
                    this@BottomNavigationDrawerFragment.dismiss()

                }
                2 ->{

                }
            }
        }

        expandableListView!!.setOnChildClickListener { parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id ->
           // Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Clicked: " + (titleList as ArrayList<String>)[groupPosition] + " -> " + listData[(titleList as ArrayList<String>)[groupPosition]]!!.get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            when(childPosition){
                0 ->{
                    this.register(adapter,2)
                    fragment(1)
                    this@BottomNavigationDrawerFragment.dismiss()
                }
                1 ->{
                    this.register(adapter,2)
                    fragment(2)
                    this@BottomNavigationDrawerFragment.dismiss()
                }
                2 ->{
                    fragment(3)
                    this@BottomNavigationDrawerFragment.dismiss()
                }


            }
            false
        }
    }



    return rootView
}



/*
override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)  */

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)


}
```

The following is my expandable **List View Adapter**:

```
class ExpandableAdapter internal constructor(private val context: 
Context, private val titleList: List<String>, private val dataList: 
LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>?>) : 
BaseExpandableListAdapter(),BottomNavigationDrawerFragment.Callback {

var selected_position = 0

override fun getChild(listPosition: Int, expandedListPosition: Int): Any {
   return this.dataList[this.titleList[listPosition]]!![expandedListPosition]
   //return this.dataList.get(this.titleList.get(listPosition))!!.get(expandedListPosition)
}

override fun getChildId(listPosition: Int, expandedListPosition: Int): Long {
    return expandedListPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getChildView(listPosition: Int, expandedListPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var convertView = convertView
    val expandedListText = getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition) as String
    if (convertView == null) {
        val layoutInflater = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null)
    }
    val image = convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
    val text = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_text)

    if(listPosition == 1){
        text.setText(expandedListText)
    }
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fresh)

    return convertView
}

override fun getChildrenCount(listPosition: Int): Int {
    //Log.d("nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn",this.dataList[this.titleList[listPosition]]!!.size.toString())
    if(listPosition == 1){
        return this.dataList[this.titleList[listPosition]]!!.size
    }
    else{
        return 0
    }

}

override fun getGroup(listPosition: Int): Any {
    return this.titleList[listPosition]
}

override fun onClickCallBack(position: Int) {
    this.selected_position =position
}
override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
    return this.titleList.size
}

override fun getGroupId(listPosition: Int): Long {
    return listPosition.toLong()
}


override fun getGroupView(listPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var convertView = convertView
    val listTitle = getGroup(listPosition) as String
    if (convertView == null) {
        val layoutInflater = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null)
    }
    val listTitleTextView = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_text)
    val image_left = convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_left)
    val image_right = convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_right)
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle)

    val layout = convertView!!.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.main_layout)
    if(listPosition == selected_position){
        layout.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
    }
    else{
        layout.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
    }


    return convertView
}

override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun isChildSelectable(listPosition: Int, expandedListPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

}

Thank you for the help!

Comment: When you dismiss the bottom sheet its instance is destroyed. When you show it again you create a new instance. You need to save whatever state you want somewhere else. SharedPrefs, a singleton, etc. Then retrieve the state in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

To retain bottom sheet dialog fragment state you can do as following way, i have created a simple example for that to understand by anyone:

First create a xml file named as

> fragment_bottomsheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_old_value"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="0" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create BottomSheetDialogFragment named as

> BottomSheetFragment

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    BottomSheetDialog dialog;
    Integer myOldValue = 0;
    TextView tvOldValue;

    public static BottomSheetFragment newInstance() {
        BottomSheetFragment fragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        tvOldValue = contentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_old_value);
        tvOldValue.setText(String.valueOf(myOldValue));
        ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
                FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                tvOldValue.setText(String.valueOf(myOldValue));
            }
        });
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public BottomSheetDialog getDialog() {
        return dialog;
    }

    public void setDialog(BottomSheetDialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    public Integer getMyOldValue() {
        return myOldValue;
    }

    public void setMyOldValue(Integer myOldValue) {
        this.myOldValue = myOldValue;
    }
}
```

Then create MainActivity and take that bottomsheetdialogfragment object as globally and do not destroy them but try to hide and show from dialog like below:

> MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnShow;
    BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnShow = findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetFragment.newInstance();
        bottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment");

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bottomSheetDialog.setMyOldValue(bottomSheetDialog.getMyOldValue() + 1);
                bottomSheetDialog.getDialog().show();     
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After watching this example, you can see that there is myOldValue in BottomSheetFragment that will print every time when dialog appears in screen with updated value. so in this way we can retain state of bottomsheet without destroying it. hope it helps everyone!

Comment: And what will be happen when activity also will be destroyed and recreated? I guess your oldValue will be 0.