# RecyclerView back to position 0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with firebase database 
When i click on the item a bottom sheet dialog should show
when the bottom sheet dialog shown the recycler back to position 0
this is the bottom sheet call from adapter

```
   holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CommentBottomSheetDialog dialog=new CommentBottomSheetDialog(context,user,items.get(position));
                dialog.show(fragmentManager,dialog.getTag());
            }
        });
```

and this is the bottom sheet load data code

```
       private void loadList() {
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                    list=new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot d:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Comments comments=d.getValue(Comments.class);
                        list.add(comments);
                    }
                    CommentsAdapter adapter=new CommentsAdapter(context,list);
                    rec.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Note:** the bottom sheet also load data from firebase

Comment: Provided info is not enough to get an idea. Please add more info to help.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have a problem that recycler return to position 0 when the bottom sheet shown 
how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

just create a SmoothScroller with the preference SNAP_TO_START:

```java
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
  @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
    return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
  }
};
```

Now you set the position where you want to scroll to, Here if you want to scroll to the top, set 0.

```java
smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
```

and pass the newly created smooth scroller to the `LayoutManager` as

```java
layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Comment: I have a problem that recycler return to position 0 when the bottom sheet shown
how can i prevent this?

Comment: You need to retain the state of BottomSheet somehow. Here, In your case, You should persist the currently scrolled index of RecyclerView to prevent resetting the scroll. Maybe this SO post can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254583/how-to-save-state-of-bbottomdialogsheetfragment-b-after-dismiss-method

Answer (score 0):

Use something like
`recyclerView.layoutManager.scrollToPosition(position)`